# R - predict() error: invalid type (builtin) for variable 'class'

Tags: r

I'm trying to use multinom() from nnet to apply regression on my data.
Here is what I've done:

```
#------------------Multinom Regression---------------#
  #regression
  glm.fit=multinom(Duration~., data=train)
  summary(glm.fit)
  #Prediction
  predsval  <-predict(glm.fit, newdata=validation[,2:11], "probs")
```

The predict() operation throws this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  invalid type (builtin) for variable 'class'
```

The predict() line was working for numerous models like decision trees and neural networks. but for the same line it throws the error on the multinom regression model.
any ideas?

EDIT:

```
> dput(train[1:5,])
structure(list(Duration = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), ActionAVG = c(1079.818182, 
8519.15, 4938.211538, 633.9230769, 487.1341463), ActionCount = c(33L, 
20L, 52L, 13L, 82L), ActionsSTD = c(1325.668286, 14333.15299, 
5746.947505, 1558.555553, 1187.325397), EventCount = c(53L, 1L, 
36L, 9L, 20L), GestureAVG = c(712.001548, 2645.481675, 1724.010753, 
2113.457711, 2757.006369), GestureCount = c(646L, 191L, 93L, 
201L, 157L), gesturesstd = c(1446.855062, 4864.355753, 1967.416169, 
1733.255691, 2572.892938), screencount = c(50L, 12L, 32L, 15L, 
78L), stddiff = c(1356.033565, 6373.766188, 3497.559543, 1770.347893, 
2679.068084), ScreenCountDist = c(13L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L), class = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Duration", 
"ActionAVG", "ActionCount", "ActionsSTD", "EventCount", "GestureAVG", 
"GestureCount", "gesturesstd", "screencount", "stddiff", "ScreenCountDist", 
"class"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT_2:

```
> dput(validation[1:5,])
structure(list(Duration = c(5, 2, 3, 3, 3), ActionAVG = c(68.2, 
909.875, 4135, 192.5, 535.75), ActionCount = c(5L, 8L, 1L, 8L, 
4L), ActionsSTD = c(29.32064119, 1362.292022, 0, 293.8877337, 
522.1917751), EventCount = c(13L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L), GestureAVG = c(1573.473684, 
2964.966667, 1973.352941, 1072.733333, 560.2692308), GestureCount = c(57L, 
60L, 34L, 15L, 26L), gesturesstd = c(3052.29873, 3258.204122, 
2452.19659, 1439.818365, 454.8399769), screencount = c(8L, 14L, 
3L, 6L, 6L), stddiff = c(2862.564254, 5449.960621, 2345.319105, 
2220.919405, 909.2036427), ScreenCountDist = c(4L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 
4L)), .Names = c("Duration", "ActionAVG", "ActionCount", "ActionsSTD", 
"EventCount", "GestureAVG", "GestureCount", "gesturesstd", "screencount", 
"stddiff", "ScreenCountDist"), row.names = c(2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you please post a sample of the data? you can use `dput(train[1:10,])`  and `dput(validation[1:10,])`

Comment: I edited the original post, tell me if it helps (the validation is the same)

Comment: try `class(validation$class)`, it should be `'factor`' , if not, that's your problem.

Comment: The result is Null. can you explain what is this variable and the cause for this? Also, do I just factor() it? I don't know about any class var anyway :}

Comment: it's not clear what's going on with your validation set, the column might not even be there, the only way to know , is to dput the validation set as well,

Comment: Done under EDIT_2

Comment: are you sure you are not regressing for the variable class instead of duration?

Comment: You can see that I applied it upon "Duration". it works fine running it and so is the summary. the predict() confuses me because it worked for previous models. only the with the multinom I receive the error.

Comment: I understand, in your validation set `duration` is present but `class` is not,  in order for this regression to work you need  `glm.fit=multinom(Duration~., data=train[,-12])`

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. I wonder where did the 12th var came from.. but thanks anyway again. Want to publish it as an answer so I can accept? :]

Comment: answer is posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exclude from the model a variable that is not present in the validation set

```
glm.fit=multinom(Duration~., data=train[,-12])
```